# Neo4j 2.0 with Eclipse Java

Tags: java, remote-access, neo4j

I want to interact with remote Neo4j server 2.0 version from Eclipse Java program. Can some one tell me,what tools and libraries do I need to achieve this. 
Please note that it need to interact with remote DB server and not the embedded Noe4j. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Neo4j JDBC driver. That should work best for your purposes:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/tree/2.0

If you've worked with a JDBC driver before it should be as easy. Just make sure to use parametrized `PreparedStatement` for your queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other options as well:

1. The native Neo4j REST API. Docs are here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api.html and an example is here: https://github.com/jimwebber/neo4j-tutorial/blob/master/src/koan/java/org/neo4j/tutorial/advanced/BasicRestApiFormerlyKoan10.java (check out the entire Koan project; it's a fantastic way to get really familiar with Neo4j's Java libs).  The example makes use of a Jersey client to call out to the Neo4j server.
2. https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding - The URL should speak for itself. There are tags for Neo4j 2.0 as well.  This binding essentially wraps the above in a nice, neat package.  Beats having to write your own wrapper.
3. Spring Data for Neo4j (http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/). If you're using Spring in your Java development, this is definitely worth a look.  The update for Neo4j 2.0 just came out a few weeks ago and should be ready for production very soon.  There are pros and cons to using SDN, but, it's super easy to use, especially if you don't need anything overly complicated.

Hope this helps!